# Problem with Chromium and Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Each time I got to specific sites on the internet which I use regularly with both Google Chrome and Chromium (I recently change from Chrome because of one question that I read here) The page loads for one second I see the site appearing and then it show me a blue screen no matter how many times I reload it.

Comment: Any specific pages you know?

Comment: Have you tried to open these specific sites in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens in chromium and there is no relation on which websites you visit so I suggest you to make sure you are using the latest version. And if you find a bug refer to http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines in order to report it.

It's also useful if you tell us more about your system, which Ubuntu release are you using? And please include the version of your Chromium/Google Chrome.

Complete removal of the software and reinstalling Chromium/Google Chrome with the latest version is recommended and usually solves a lot of issues like this.

Good luck!